# simple escape parentheses to count them

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I am trying to make separate counts of open and closed parentheses in a JavaScript string.  How can I write the regex to accomplish this?

Here is what I have so far, which is throwing errors:

```
($scope.somevariable.match(new RegExp("\(", "g")) || []).length
```

and:

```
($scope.somevariable.match(new RegExp("\)", "g")) || []).length
```

The results of google searches on this topic all have very complicated expressions.  This question is about a very simple example of just counting the number of `(` and `)` separately.

I am using AngularJS.

Comment: It is another duplicate. Double ``\`` in  a regexp constructor, or best - use `.match(/\)/g)`.

Comment: This is a duplicate, it can be solved using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/432503/3499931).